# Add Item to Jagged Array

Tags: c#, arrays, jagged-arrays

It is a homework.
I want to store names and total votes of electoral candidates for country provinces.
In this practice I should use arrays.
Since the number of candidates is not known I thinks I should use Jagged arrays.
But number of provinces is known so I wrote :

```
 int ProvincesCount = 30;
 string[][][] JaggedArray = new string[ProvincesCount][][];
```

I want to enter candidates names and their votes count into array with a Loop.Then I should determine top people in per province.

Please help me how I can enter information into Array ?

Comment: consider that a jagged array may not be the best way to structure data if the number of items is not known ahead of time.

Comment: @anthony 
So what data structure should I use ? 
In array family

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/array-resize) you can find how to resize array. 
You might have to give an initial size. Its better to
make a good guess for initial size so you don't have to resize
alot.

Might I suggest you use classes to represent Provinces and Candidates
if you have reached this topic.

Answer (score 1):

There *is* an array.resize method which you can use since it's homework.  However, please remember when you get to more advanced topics this would not be the way to go and something like a linked list would serve better, depening on the application.